# C++ New map element equivalent to modifying existing map element?

Tags: c++, insert, stdmap

I am using a map to store an index (long long int) as a key, and a number density (double). When I am modifying the number densities, I check if the index of interest has been defined as a key yet: (a) if it has, modify it's associated density (b) if it hasn't, create a key and associated density.

However, I found that the same actions seem to be performed if I do as follows. Say I define a map

```
std::map < long long int, double> test;
```

Then assign/modify density values as follows:

```
test[100] += d100;

test[101] += d101;
```

...

for some densities dN. The interesting thing is that in doing this, my original check if a key exists seems unnecessary as I can define and then modify a key as:

```
test[200] += 5.;

test[200] += 7.;
```

It seems like it is much more efficient if I don't check if a key exists already, given that my map is going to be very long and I will be modifying it a lot. Is this okay coding practice?

Comment: Yes, it is OK coding practice. When no element with a given key is present, `operator[]` adds one, with a *value-initialized* value. For built-in types this means *zero-initialized*. This is by design, it is not a fluke, so you can rely on that behaviour.

Comment: Also, if you don't need ordering but need speed instead, you may want to look at [std::unordered_map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map)